# Multiple monitors via Dell DisplayLink not working in 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, wayland, displaylink

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 (was using Elementary OS before) on my Dell Latitude, which has two monitors connected via a DisplayLink dock. I managed to get three screen (laptop screen + two external) working on Elemantary OS after installing the DisplayLink drivers from the Dell website. On Ubuntu 18.04 I am not seeing the external monitors, even though I managed to install DispplayLink drivers.

I have tried with NVIDIA proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-390) and with X.Org nouveau (xserver-xorg-video-nouveau).

*EDIT (Oct 2018):* Installed the latest Dell DisplayLink driver which says it is working with Ubuntu 18.04 from http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu
Issue remains.

Another issue, possibly related: I can only boot into Ubuntu using "Ubuntu on Wayland", the default Ubuntu just goes right back to the login screen after I type in my password.

```
$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07d0
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell CM238 HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Comment: I managed to get to the point where I cannot choose "Ubuntu in Wayland" any more, after uncommenting WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf but after that I cannot reliably login any more (I managed to logon once). My keyboard and mouse don't work any more and I cannot login at all.

Comment: I assume it is the DisplayLink driver which isn't compatible with Ubuntu 148.04 and/or Wayland. Might just need to wait for Dell to bring out an updated version.

Comment: Check the forums [here](https://displaylink.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=29).  There is an email list for updates.  You can also post [here](https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/34104508-support-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Just installed the new version of the DisplayLink drivers and the issue remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that using Wayland was the culprit, possibly combined with the DisplayLink drivers. Installing the latest drivers (4.4) from http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu and switch back to to "Ubuntu" (the default) in the login screen resolved the issue.

Comment: I installed driver version 5.1 and could not use the monitors. I deinstalled and installed 4.4 and it worked. However with quite a lag :´(